# z3py on rise4fun unavailable since several weeks

Tags: z3, z3py

I was using the rise4fun z3py website a lot and I really liked it.

However, since several weeks when trying to access

http://rise4fun.com/z3py

I get redirected to

http://rise4fun.com

The site http://rise4fun.com/z3 is working, but thats not for trying the Z3 python API, right?

It the z3py website taken down intendedly or is the something wrong?

Thanks & kind regards,
 Klaus

Comment: I couldn't find the post, but Leonardo mentioned somewhere it was taken down for security reasons (someone found a way to execute elevated commands or ones that the sanitizer should have removed) and they are working on getting it back online, but I don't know the timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

The Z3Py website and tutorials are temporarily offline because of [security issues](http://tomforb.es/breaking-out-of-secured-python-environments). They will remain offline until these issues are fixed.